# Simple_form and rails generate scaffolding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

So I am making a web application that can process background checks for a casino. I am using the simple_form gem to handle the data entry.

So I wanted to make a Model called Applicant, and one of the parameters is type:string.  Either the applicant is an individual applying for a gaming license or a business applying for a vendor's license. This is my first time using the rails framework.

I typed rails generate scaffolding Applicant type:string into the command line.

On the view I wanted to make type a radio button. Business or individual.  However when I click create applicant the type is not saved. All of the other fields are full except for type.

```
              <section>
                <h3>Address Information</h3>

                    <%= f.input :address %>
                    <%= f.input :line2 %>
                    <%= f.input :city %>
                    <%= f.input :state %>
                    <%= f.input :zip %><br>
                <h3>What Kind of application is this</h3>
                  <%= radio_button_tag :type, "Business", @type %>Business 
                  <%= radio_button_tag :type, "Individual", @type %>Individual<br> 

                <div class="form-actions">
                  <%= f.button :submit, label:"Submit"%>
                </div>
              </section>
```

I really appreciate any help. I just don't understand what I am doing wrong, and why no data is being stored in the type field.

Thanks

Comment: What is `@type` set to?  When you say not saved, are you saying you inspected `params` and `type` is not there?  Also, what does your rendered HTML look like and what do you want it to look like?

Comment: When I look in the controller I do not see an @type variable that was generated. Should I set one like @type=[Business, Individual] under new in the applicant controller?Yes when I do a params dump or go to the show page type is left blank.

Comment: the rendered html looks fine but the buttons don't do anything

Comment: If you are not sure what `@type` is for, you can remove it from the view.  Class instance variables (starting with '@') are defined by you in the controller so that you can include dynamic content in your view.  Can you post your rendered `HTML` for the `radio button`?

Comment: <h3>What Kind of application is this</h3>
                      <input type="radio" name="type" id="type_Business" value="Business" />Business 
                      <input type="radio" name="type" id="type_Individual" value="Individual" />Individual<br>

Comment: Change `type` to some other name.  `type` is a reserved `Ruby` term so that could be causing a problem.  To make the change, create a database migration, change the column name and then run `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: I changed type to typeOfApplication and there was no change. Still on the show page there is nothing under typeOfApplication

Comment: Everything looks good to me.  Can you edit your post to include your `params` hash?

Comment: params.require(:applicant).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :social, :email, :address, :line2, :city, :state, :zip, :phone1, :phone2, :company, :comments, :dob, :typeOfApplication)

Comment: forgive my ignorance but is this what you meant by the params hash?

Comment: No worries JP - you were crushing it up until then given you are new to Rails!  I am looking for the `params` hash which is passed from the view back to the controller on Submit.  Let me know if you need help capturing.  That hash should have all of the submitted form fields.

Comment: Should I do something like
<% params.each do |key, value| %>
      <% key+ " => "+value  %>

Comment: I would add `puts params` at the top of your post/create controller action.

Comment: Hey I figured it out by changing it to a boolean I was able to run my code, which is annoying and a total hack around. Next time I am going to really study the code . I think that my problem was using a generator

Comment: Great to hear it is working.  I saw that thread with William but do not agree.  I would not recommend scaffolding but using generators is standard Rails.  Sorry I missed the `boolean` issue...

Comment: I just got stuck again wow this framework is so easy to break. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

Two things to try:

- The word "type" is used in html inputs frequently, example: `type="Submit"`
- You might be failing to associate your 'radio_button_tag' with the data object associated with the form. Note how in the inputs above you have:

  ```
              <%= f.input :address %>
              <%= f.input :line2 %>
              <%= f.input :city %>
              <%= f.input :state %>`
  ```

Ive never used the radio_button_tag helper before so I dont know if you need to chain it with the object.
    Confirm that you're using the appropriate syntax

Comment: I changed the field name to typeOfApplication and then changed type everywhere in the views, but still nothing

Comment: In the sample of code you provided, it doesnt show the embedded ruby for the form, like : "<%= simple_form_for @applicant do |f| %>" is that there?

Comment: Yes that is there and all of the other form inputs are being saved correctly only problem is with the radio buttons

Comment: William, Let me ask you like this. If you were going to use 'rails generate scaffolding' and wanted to make a Model which only had one field and that field was going to be input using radio buttons. How would you do it?

Comment: Firstly, its not obvious when first coming to Rails - however - generators are not supposed to be used during actual development, theyre supposed to serve as an educational tool.  A. Run the generator B. see what it poops out C. learn.  That being said, the form field for the radio button should like this:  `<%= f.radio_button :type, "Business", @type %>Business`  ...and to answer your question about the generator, it would look like this: `rails g scaffolding <model_name> <thing:boolean> `

Comment: I dont know if that generator will make the field youre hoping for, but its what I would start with if I HAD to use scaffolding

Comment: Ok looks good I will keep that in mind in the future I really appreciate the help and I will let you know how it goes.